# MySQL limit 1 get random (1,8)

Tags: mysql, select, limit

Ok so i need to ran a simple `select from table limit 1` but i need the row either the first row or any row between 1-8.

I thought something like this, but then realised that there is no ID in the rows the only unique ID is the phone number

So i am wondering how would I limit 1 result but pick a random row from the first 1-8

Comment: how do you define `first` then?

Comment: normally its just the way it was inserted in there - the latest one is at the bottom and the first one is at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this,

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName LIMIT 0,7) as derivedTableName    
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

With sub query, you need to serialized what will be the 1st row and what will be 8th row.
Next take a random row from them.